# Spark UDF vs flatMap()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

From my understanding Spark UDF's are good when you want to do column transformations.
But if you have a df that looks something like this:

```
def transform_row(row: Tuple[str, str]) -> Tuple(str, str, str, str):
  person_id = row[0]
  person_name = row[1]
  for result in get_person_details(person_id):
    yield (person_id, person_name, result[0], result[1], result[2])

results = df.rdd.flatMap(transform_row)
```

Using an existing dataframe - use some of it's fields to call a function that returns me further details which I need to yield as a tuple of values.

My question is: the same can be achieved using udf. Will that be more efficient than the flatMap?

Comment: Both UDFs and `flatMap` should be avoided when possible.  Can you post an example of the DataFrame you're starting with and the result you'd like to see?  That'll make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @Powers: I updated it. The data is simple.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like something that in original df could be a struct, you can simply unpack it if it is a struct via

```
col("col_name.*")
```

This will be much more preformant than udf or flat map.

Could you run a printSchema() on your df?

If it is an array that you need to flatten then it depends on the cardinality but similar should still remains since it looks like you are normalising schema.
Of course for arrays you cant use "*" operator and you would need to go via

```
col("col_name").getItem("index")
```

You could still manage this via some collections operations and have it prety much flexible.

I am assuming get_person_details is performing some lookup in a hash map which you can replace with broadcast join.

A bit broader code snippet would help for further suggestions.